# Create an object from Firestore document flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create an object from a Firestore document based on the current user's uid. I'm not sure it is not working.

Here is the widget that I am wanting the object in.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<MyUser>(context); // object that has the Firebase UID
    return StreamBuilder<UserData>(
      stream: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userData,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          UserData userData = snapshot.data;
          print(userData.toString());
          return // profile page;
        } else {
          return Loading();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

The snapshot is always null and returns loading. Here is the stream code.

```
// userData from snapshot
  UserData _userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data();
    return UserData(
      uid: uid,
      name: data['name'],
      imageURL: data['imageURL'],
      fitLevel: data['fitLevel'],
      stickerList: data['stickerList'],
      evoChallenge: data['evoChallenge'],
    );
  }

  // get user doc stream
  Stream<UserData> get userData {
    return userCollection.doc(uid).snapshots().map(_userDataFromSnapshot);
  }
```

Inside of the `-userDataFromSnapshot` function, I am able to print the data and everything inside of the document is there.

I've used essentially the same code for a different project and it worked just fine. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
I changed `-userDataFromSnapshot` to print out its results :

```
UserData _userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data();
    print('uid : $uid');
    UserData myData = UserData(
      uid: uid,
      name: data['name'],
      imageURL: data['imageURL'],
      fitLevel: data['fitLevel'],
      stickerList: data['stickerList'],
      evoChallenge: data['evoChallenge'],
    );

    print('mydata : ${myData.uid}');
    return UserData(
      uid: uid,
      name: data['name'],
      imageURL: data['imageURL'],
      fitLevel: data['fitLevel'],
      stickerList: data['stickerList'],
      evoChallenge: data['evoChallenge'],
    );
  }
```

It skips the second print. Console:

```
I/flutter ( 6605): uid : oPVUiuublPOTUBjP7k1XIJwH9nU2
I/flutter ( 6605): afterloading
```

Comment: It looks good to me. Are you 100% sure that the correct uid is being passed here and the user document does have contents in it?

Comment: Yes. I was printing out the uid to check and was printing out the mapped snapshot. I'm so confused

Comment: I'm not know if it is the problem, but I avoid to use StreamBuilder in this way, passing a new Stream instance to the StreamBuilder.stream param. Every way the StreamBuilder is instantiated, a new Stream instance is maked too. I always use a class field to store the stream. And, to test StreamBuilder, I always use flutter Hot Restart (with Hot Reload I didn't note some code issues).

Comment: isn't it `UserData userData = snapshot.data();`instead of `UserData userData = snapshot.data;`?